# WSO2 AS 5.3.0 Linkage Error with slf4j

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

I try to deploy a war web application into WSO2 AS (5.3.0) and get an unexpected error regarding to slf4j as below,

[image: LinkageError]

The application is working well in both Tomcat 8.0.32 and Wildfly 10 Application Server.

[image: Slf4j in the lib]

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Have you bundled slf4j libs into your war file?

Comment: Yes, slf4j jar is in the lib in the war file, you can from the picture, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If Carbon runtime environment is not needed, you may add the `webapp-classloading.xml` into your webapp, and configure it to use `Tomcat` runtime as explained in "[Webapp Classloading](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS521/Webapp+ClassLoading)" document.